# Sort an Arraylist of objects using merge sort

Tags: java, algorithm, sorting

I have an ArrayList of Item objects consisting of OrderNo and CustomerID. I want to order the list using merge sort according to OrderNo with their corresponding CustomerID intact.

I understand the merge sort part of the problem as I've done it on normal arrays and even ArrayLists. But the problem in this scenario comes when I have to match the sorted OrderNo with its corresponding CustomerID.

```
public class Items {
    private int orderNo;
    private int customerID;

    public Items(int r, int c, String p) {
        this.orderNo = r;
        this.customerID = c;
    }
   //getters and setters
}
```

Then I create an array list of Items and feed them values for orderNo and customerID.

```
ArrayList<Items> i = new ArrayList<Items>();
i.add(new Items(orderNo, customerID);
```

I need to sort them according to orderNo but **also make sure the customerID matches with their corresponding orderNo**.

Here's the merge sort implementation:

```
 private static ArrayList mergeSort(ArrayList<Integer> left, ArrayList<Integer> right, ArrayList<Integer> whole) {
        int leftIndex = 0;
        int rightIndex = 0;
        int wholeIndex = 0;

        while (leftIndex < left.size() && rightIndex < right.size()) {
            if ( (left.get(leftIndex) < right.get(rightIndex))) {
                whole.set(wholeIndex, left.get(leftIndex));
                leftIndex++;
            } else {
                whole.set(wholeIndex, right.get(rightIndex));
                rightIndex++;
            }
            wholeIndex++;
        }

        ArrayList<Integer> rest;
        int restIndex;
        if (leftIndex >= left.size()) {
            // The left ArrayList has been use up...
            rest = right;
            restIndex = rightIndex;
        } else {
            // The right ArrayList has been used up...
            rest = left;
            restIndex = leftIndex;
        }

        for (int i=restIndex; i<rest.size(); i++) {
            whole.set(wholeIndex, rest.get(i));
            wholeIndex++;
        }

        return whole;
    }

public static ArrayList<Integer> merge(ArrayList<Integer> a)
    {
        int total = a.size();
        if(total < 2)
        {
            return a;
        }
        else
        {
            int mid = a.size() / 2;
            ArrayList<Integer> left = new ArrayList<>();
            ArrayList<Integer> right = new ArrayList<>();

            for(int i = 0; i < mid; i++)
            {
                left.add(a.get(i));
            }
            for(int i = mid; i < total; i ++)
            {
                right.add(a.get(i));
            }

            left = merge(left);
            right = merge(right);

            return mergeSort(left, right, a);
        }
    }
```

The above implementation works with a simple arraylist of values. I tried changing it to work with Items object by filtering out the orderNo's from Items and feeding it to the method... but I'm sure that's not the way to go about it since that messes up the relationship each orderNo has with each of its corresponding customerId.

Comment: Your question is vague and unclear. Please show some code demonstrating your problem.

Comment: why not implement comparable's compareTo method and use collections.sort method provided by Java?

Comment: @AvinashAnand Since you understand the question, please explain it to the rest of us.

Comment: I could but I want to know how I'd go about solving it using merge sort (or any other sort for that matter). The sorting is not the issue for me, the issue is getting each of the customerID to match with their corresponding sorted OrderNo.

Comment: @shmosel - It looks like user is trying to implement merge sort (maybe to practice algorithm), while Java provides sorting just by using comparable interface and collections.sort function.

Comment: @AvinashAnand Using `Collections.sort()` will not fulfill the *assignment* of writing a *merge sort* on `ArrayList` by `OrderNo`.

Comment: @ZeroDarkThirty - if you have implemented mergesort on arraylist, why cant the same be applied on arraylist of objects?

Comment: @shmosel I've updated the OP with some more context.

Comment: @Andreas - What I am trying to say is why re-invent wheel? Why not use functionality provided by language itself? And if you are learning algorithm, then this question is not strictly relevent to Java.

Comment: @ZeroDarkThirty That's a little better, but I still don't understand the concern. Why do you think sorting your `Item`s would cause their data to be mismatched?

Comment: @AvinashAnand Because that is not the **assignment** *(whether school assigned or self-assign as an exercise, doesn't matter)*.

Comment: @shmosel Let me add my merge sort implementation in the OP. It will give you a better idea.

Comment: @ZeroDarkThirty *FYI:* "OP" means Original Poster, aka you. The text you wrote is the "Question".

Comment: @Andreas - I agree with your point. I am saying that if the assignment is about algorithm, then tag as Java should not be used. And if you say its a problem of Java, then use the feature provided by language.

Comment: @ZeroDarkThirty Echoing schmosel here... each object has an `orderNo` and a `customerId`, and if you do something that rearranges the objects, like a sort, the `orderNo` and `customerId` will move around with the objects, so the corresponding fields will stay together.  A sort doesn't cause an object's fields to jump out and land in other objects.  I don't really understand your concern either.

Comment: @AvinashAnand The assignment is about the algorithm *in Java*, not in Fortran or some other language. Tagging `java` is perfectly fine, since it's a question about how to do it in Java.

Comment: @shmosel I've added the merge sort implementation to the original post to give better context.

Comment: Ok, so the problem is that your methods expect to work with `ArrayList<Integer>`. You need to change that to `ArrayList<Item>`, and apply your comparisons to the object retrieved from that list. E.g., `if ( (left.get(leftIndex).getOrderNo() < right.get(rightIndex).getOrderNo()))`.

Comment: @shmosel I think we're going somewhere now. Thanks so much. I'll follow along with your solution and see if it works.

Comment: @shmosel Just wanted to say that your solution worked out for me. Thanks again! I'm not sure why I got all those downvotes though lol.

Comment: Glad to help. I assume the downvotes are because the question initially lacked specifics and was therefore very unclear. Next time try to provide the full context up front.

Answer (score 3):

> I need to sort them according to orderNo but also make sure the customerID matches with their corresponding orderNo.

If you implement sort correctly, it is not going to mess up the relationship between customerID and orderNo.  (The sort algorithm *should not* be calling the setter methods on the `Items` objects.  You should be moving the items in the array / array list.)

So this question really boils down to implementing merge sort.  Since this is (apparently) a homework assignment, giving you source code defeats the purpose.  You would be advised to just knuckle down and write it yourself.

---

One hint though:  It will be simpler if you copy the `ArrayList` elements to an `Items[]` array, sort the array, then copy them back.  Something like this:

```
Items[] array = new Items[list.size()];
list.toArray(array);

// Sort the array here

list.clear();
list.addAll(Arrays.asList(array));
```

---

Looking at your code:

Your big mistake (IMO) is that you are trying to sorting `ArrayList<Integer>` objects.  You should be sorting an `ArrayList<Items>`.  (I haven't looked at the method implementation ...)

Comment: I've added the merge sort implementation to the original post to give better context.

Comment: I know it should be ArraList<Items>. That isn't the main concern. There's some internal logic of the method that needs changing.

Comment: Erm, no.  If you sort an `ArrayList<Items>` then you don't have the problem of the order numbers and item ids getting separated.  The *right* way to solve that problem is to not have it in the first place!